# Find position number for each group (Table.PositionOf() with Table.Group) in Power Query (M language)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'd like to find number of position first "TAK" in column "taknie" for each group (column Grupa).

This is my table.

| Grupa | taknie |
| --- | --- |
| g1 | NIE |
| g1 | **TAK** |
| g2 | NIE |
| g2 | NIE |
| g2 | NIE |
| g2 | **TAK** |
| g3 | **TAK** |
| g3 | TAK |
| g3 | NIE |
| g3 | TAK |
| g4 | NIE |
| g4 | **TAK** |
| g4 | TAK |
| g5 | NIE |

I've tried in Advanced editor

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabela1"]}[Content],
    Grupa = Table.Group(Source, "Grupa", {"wynik", each Table.PositionOf(
        Source, 
        [taknie = "TAK"], 
        Occurrence.First,
        "taknie"
    ) + 1})
in
    Grupa
```

but it doesn't work properly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghNFl.png)

Instead of 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, should be

| Grupa | wynik |
| --- | --- |
| g1 | 2 |
| g2 | 4 |
| g3 | 1 |
| g4 | 2 |
| g5 | 0 |

Comment: Please paste sample data as text.

Comment: Please explain what position first means to you. I can't tell the pattern from your data

Comment: First "TAK" value for each group. I made bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSjdUUNJR8vN0VYrVgfFCHL0hPCMUOYI8uD5jQjy4PlQ5ExQ5E0w5OM8UrjIWAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Grupa = _t, taknie = _t]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Grupa"}, {{"First", each List.PositionOf  ([#"taknie"], "TAK")+1, type nullable text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: OMG, it works. Really really thank you !!!!!! I didn't know List.PositionOf function :(

Comment: kudos for even understanding the question. Good on you